# GPS COORDS READING

Tags: c++, variables, gps

I am trying to make a program that to which a used will enter this "$GPGGA,004536.289,9876.5375,N,06540.9373,E,1,04,3.2,2550.2,M,,,,0000*0E"
and the program will show only what's before before "N" and "E" like in this case it will be "9876.5375" and "06540.9373"

At first I thought I could make it read the entire thing as different variables chain like:

`cin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g>>h>>l;` and then show only the variables I want but it works so weird and the variables it shows have nothing to do with my entry

This is the program https://prnt.sc/oS5aElQoUC65

This is what it shows after I enter the gps code https://prnt.sc/jRyLhD_ik2G2

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `cin >> a >> b >> ...` does not read comma seperated values into `a`, `b`, `...`. What made you think that this should work?

Comment: I am very new, I have no idea what is supposed to work or what not, I just tried it :p

Comment: Welcome! As long as you follow the guidance in ["What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/11107541), then [you don't need to tell us that you are new to `X`](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296391/11107541).

Answer (score 0):

Your data types are NOT **int**. They are actually **float** or **double** or **char/string**.
Fix the data types and enter them WITHOUT ",". Just a space between them or [enter]

UPDATE
change the line with the declarations (line 15) for this one:

```
std::string a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, l;
```

Run it and it will be easier for your to understand your code.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, excuse my lack of knowledge but when you say float or double or char/string, do you mean all of them? like I need to make each variable to it's type?
About the "," it has to be there, the user will have to enter the coors in that same way I copied it above.

Comment: The coordinates are doubles: double a, b, c;
If there are literals like "N" define them as std::string.
std::string d, e, f;

Actually everything can be a string, but if you need a numeric value you will have to convert the string into a number.

For simplicity change "int" for "std::string" and run it.

Everything will be strings and it will be easier for you.

Comment: I did tried that, it sadly give me the entire entry back as the value of "a"

Comment: Because there were NO spaces. "cin" has specific rules and you want to use it you need to comply with them. Inputs are separated by whitespaces, not by commas. It' not CSV "comma separated values".